# How to set Angular header value in localstorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular7

```
saveStudentDetails(values) {
  const studentData = {};

  studentData['id'] =  values.id;
  studentData['password'] =  values.password;

  this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    // Here should be the value of the header from backend to be store on localstorage
    this.toastr.success('You are logged in', 'Success !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
    this.router.navigate(['/address']);
  },
    err => {
      console.log('status code ->' + err.status);
      this.toastr.error('Please try again', 'Error !', { positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' });
 });
```

[image: Autorization header]

I have a JWT token that has been set in the Authorization header when the user logged in into the system, how can i get the token from the Authorization header and put the token into localstorage so that i can pass the jwt token to other routes too? Thank you very much.

Comment: Need more explaination!

Comment: how does `crudService.loginstudent()` function look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.crudService.loginstudent(studentData).subscribe(result => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', result.headers.get('Authorization'));    
});
```

Comment: not working for me, Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Even if the code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/api-calls-rpb2jt) link of what you are trying to do

add following in your code: 
`localStorage.setItem('token',res.headers.get(TOKEN_NAME));`

Additionally, in your case, there is missing `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` that indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.

Comment: can i see the full coding? and i have tried the code you have given but it said property headers does not exist on type 'object'

Comment: I updated the stackblitz link please check. Now it refers to the actual code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/api-calls-rpb2jt

Comment: Hmm, how can i fix the property headers does not exist on type 'object' ?? It must have something to do with my service

Comment: Additionally, there is one important header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers
` missing in your response that might be the reason due to which you are getting Access-Control-Expose-Headers. I have updated the same in answer

Answer (score 0):

> localStorage.setItem('Url', this.router.url);